# Condition on $c_1 , c_2 , c_3$ of the LPP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the Linear programming problem

$$\max c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$$

such that $$x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq4$$

$$x_1 \leq 2$$

$$x_3 \leq 3$$

$$3x_1+x_3 \leq 7$$

$$x_1,x_2, x_3 \geq 0$$

If $(1, 0, 3)$ is an optimal solution , then

1) $c_1 \leq c_2 \leq c_3$

2) $c_3 \leq c_1 \leq c_2$

3) $c_2 \leq c_3 \leq c_1$

4) $c_2 \leq c_1 \leq c_3$

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the point $(1,0,3)$ is an optimal solution, the maximum value of the objective function in the feasible region is 
$$c_1 + 3c_3$$
Since the point $(0,1,3)$ is feasible, it follows that
$$c_2+ 3c_3 \le c_1 + 3c_3$$
hence $c_2 \le c_1$.

Since the point $\left(\frac{3}{2},0,\frac{5}{2}\right)$ is feasible, it follows that
$$\frac{3}{2}c_1 + \frac{5}{2}c_3 \le c_1 + 3c_3$$
hence $c_1 \le c_3$.

Therefore $c_2 \le c_1 \le c_3$.

Comment: how you get other two feasible solution, is it possible to find out without solve?

Comment: You can verify that those points are feasible simply by checking that the constraints are satisfied. As to how I found them, the idea was to trade some of one variable for some of another one, find the associated objective value, and compare it against the optimal value. There was no "solving" at all.

Comment: I thought, assuming one variable zero and solving other two variable. @quasi

Comment: There are lots of feasible solutions.That's not the issue. The key was to fins feasible solutions leading to useful comparisons. For that, I just took a simple "trading" approach. The point is that they _work_ to clinch the comparisons.

Comment: I am sorry but what is "trading" approach @quasi

Comment: subtacting some quantity from one coordinate, and giving it to another.

Comment: Did you verify that the points which I said were feasible all satisfy the constaints?

Comment: yes, I checked that.

Comment: Then those points are feasible. It follows that the value of the objective function at those points is less than or equal to the value of the objective function at the point $(1,0,3)$. Which yields the required comparisons.